# Security about erc 20 token smart contract

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20, security

Is there any paid resources out there that you recommend that could check the security of my ERC 20 token smart contract. Thank you to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some firms that would do that for you:

- Hacken - Website: https://hacken.io/
- Quantstamp - Website: https://quantstamp.com/
- Trail of Bits - Website: https://www.trailofbits.com/
- OpenZeppelin - Website: https://openzeppelin.com/
- ConsenSys Diligence - Website: https://diligence.consensys.net/
- Certik - Website: https://certik.io/
- LeastAuthority - Website: https://leastauthority.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a smart contract scanner. This should be helpful - https://solidityscan.com/.
I've been using it for quite some time now.